# Generating SNMP traps from Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm lookin at the camel SNMP component: http://camel.apache.org/snmp.html and it looks like it's a consumer only component.

Am I misunderstanding? Is there a way to generate SNMP traps from within a route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not yet, but it has been requested: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-5271

Comment: Seems funny that they implemented only a consumer when they were implementing that component.

I guess I'll just use a processor as @Petter had suggested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As boday stated. However, you could of course do SNMP stuff within a bean or processor using regular Java. Maybe with a third party lib such as http://www.snmp4j.org/